# Pass value to another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm getting a value from SQL server like this:

```
 var userId = cmd.Parameters["@user_id"].Value;
```

If I try to show the value above, It shows properly so It's clearly not from my query.

Now, If I try to pass to the other viewModel and show it on that form, I keep getting '0' as a value. I'm sending the value using this:

```
  Window2 X= new Window2();
  var taskViewModel = (XViewModel)X.DataContext;
  taskViewModel.userID = Convert.ToInt32(userId.ToString());
  X.ShowDialog();
```

As suggested in the comments, I've tried the following:

```
 Window2 X = new Window2();            
 XViewModel Y = new XViewModel ();
 X.DataContext = Y;
 Y.userID = Convert.ToInt32(userId.ToString());
 X.Show();
```

userID in the second form (XViewModel) is an int.

Second form code:

```
    private int _userID;

      public int userID
      {
          get { return _userID; }
          set
          {
              _userID = value;
              NotifyOfPropertyChange("userID");
          }
      }

...
MessageBox.Show(userID.ToString());
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @GrantWinney  `userId` will return 8 in this case. (based on the login of the user but never 0). and now and you mentioned it, `taskViewModel.userID` is returning 8 as well (the correct value) exactly after setting it but in the new form, It's 0.

Comment: @GrantWinney I added the code and It's not bound anywhere. I'm just trying to show it using a MessageBox to see If the proper value passed.

Comment: @GrantWinney It's being called in the `Public XViewModel` so It should show as soon as the window opens and no, I don't have any other variables on that form.

Comment: I think you want to set the data context of the new window to the view model, not the other way around

Comment: How exactly can I do that? @Crowcoder

Comment: X.DataContext = taskViewModel; You'll have to new up the view model first of course.

Comment: @Crowcoder Done (added to the original post) but the result is still 0.